# How to solve SSL - certificate verify failed exception while pact verification, service provider against broker (https broker) using pact-python lib

Tags: python, pact-python

Facing below error while communicating with https pact broker url, using pact-python lib for contract verification test against broker.

Conn close because of connect error SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed.

I have already installed required certificates on container (Docker environment) where the code is running.

Below is the sample code:

```
broker_opts():
    return {
        "broker_url": "https://ebpact01.devlab2k.testnet.rim.net:443",
        "publish_verification_results": True
    }

def test_user_service_provider_against_broker(server, broker_opts):
    verifier = Verifier(provider="user@provider", provider_base_url=PROVIDER_URL)

    success, logs = verifier.verify_with_broker(
        **broker_opts,
        verbose=True,
        provider_states_setup_url=f"{PROVIDER_URL}/_pact/provider_states",
        enable_pending=False,
    )

    assert success == 0
```

Sample Docker file :

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

COPY ./ .

RUN pwd
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install openssl \
    && apt-get install ca-certificates

#Add certificate required to access broker
ADD 'http://certificate-url/Root-CA-1.crt'   $capath/broker-root-ca1.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

RUN export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
RUN export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/broker-root-ca1.crt

#invokes pytest.main method
CMD ["python3", "./test/invoke_pact_test.py"]
```

Sample Docker compose file :

```
  pactverify:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: deploy/docker/dockerfile-pact
    image: app-pact:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    environment:
      - PACT_BROKER=$PACT_BROKER
```

Stack trace :

Error making request - OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed , attempt 1 of 3
Error making request - OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed , attempt 2 of 3
Error making request - OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed , attempt 3 of 3
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in` block in connect'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in` connect'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in` start'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/hal/http_client.rb:62:in `block in perform_request' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/retry.rb:23:in` until_true'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/hal/http_client.rb:50:in `perform_request' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/hal/http_client.rb:25:in` get'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/hal/link.rb:49:in `get' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/pact_broker/fetch_pact_uris_for_verification.rb:57:in` index'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/pact_broker/fetch_pact_uris_for_verification.rb:42:in `call' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/pact_broker/fetch_pact_uris_for_verification.rb:38:in` call'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-1.62.0/lib/pact/pact_broker.rb:18:in `fetch_pact_uris_for_verification' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/aggregate_pact_configs.rb:46:in` pacts_for_verification'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/aggregate_pact_configs.rb:39:in `pacts_urls_from_broker' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/aggregate_pact_configs.rb:26:in` call'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/aggregate_pact_configs.rb:10:in `call' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/app.rb:211:in` all_pact_urls'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/app.rb:225:in `warn_empty_pact_set' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/app.rb:40:in` call'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/app.rb:35:in `call' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/cli/verify.rb:49:in` verify'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in` start'
from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pact-provider-verifier-1.36.1/lib/pact/provider_verifier/cli/custom_thor.rb:17:in `start' from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pact/bin/pact/lib/app/pact-provider-verifier.rb:33:in` '
opening connection to broker.url:443 ...
opened
starting SSL for broker.url:443 ...
SSL established
Conn close because of connect error SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
opening connection to broker.url:443 ...
opened
starting SSL for broker.url:443 ...
SSL established
Conn close because of connect error SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
opening connection to broker.url:443 ...
opened
starting SSL for broker.url:443 ...
SSL established
Conn close because of connect error SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Comment: Hi. Can you add some more details, like Docker and docker compose configuration, the stack trace of the error, how did you install the certs, OS info, etc? It is difficult to understand what is going on with the above-provided information.

Comment: Added docker and docker-compose file.

Comment: It seems the pact verification is failing with SSL error. The issue on pact-python(https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-python/issues/143) seems similar to the instance described above. Alternatively, you can disable ssl verification for local testing(https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/issues/240), though this should be the last resort.
Out of interest, why are you running verifier inside the container where you are running broker? Ideally, the broker should be running in a container and the verifier in a separate container or on local.

Comment: pact broker which I am using is hosted over intranet, I can access the same from browser as well, while on companies vpn and running the pact test in same network.

Answer (score 1):

Is your self signed certificate?

I would advise reading the below

https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/advanced_topics/using-tls#connecting-to-a-pact-broker-running-over-tls

and raising an issue on the repo, as well as a repo as a sample.

We hang out over at https://slack.pact.io

Does it work if you disable ssl on the verifier?